# Show that two ideals are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the ideal $I = (13x+16y, 11x+13y)$ in the ring R = $\mathbb{Z}[x,y].$

Prove that $I=(x-2y, 3x+y)$ by using mutual inclusion.

I'm confused on how to start...do I begin by multiplying the elements in the ideal by a general element of R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that both elements of one generating set are $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations of elements from the other generating set.  In general, you would use $R$-linear combinations, but due to degree considerations you can use integers.

As an example, you want to find relations like $-4(x-2y) + 5(3x+y) =  11x+13y$.

Comment: Thanks! So, do I just need to find one linear combination going each way? Meaning, one linear combination of (x-2y) and (3x+y) and one linear combination of (13x+16y) and (11x+13y) that generates something in the other ideal?

Comment: You need to show two equations in each direction, one to show that each generator lies in the other ideal

Comment: So we've found that $−4(x−2y)+5(3x+y)=11x+13y$.
And I've figured out that $-5(x-2y)+6(3x+y)=13x+16y$,
$-5(13x+16y)+6(11x+13y)=x-2y$,
$-4(13x+16y)+5(11x+13y)=13x+y$.
It's pretty crazy that they use the same integer coefficients! So, how exactly do I conclude that the ideals are included in each other and therefore equal?

Comment: Do the first two tell me that $(13x+16y,11x+13y) \subseteq (x-2y,3x+y)$ and the second two tell me that $(x-2y,3x+y) \subseteq (13x+16y,11x+13y)$?

Comment: @Bob, exactly that, you should check why that implication holds if you don't believe it

Comment: Ah ok, great! I figured it out just as you answered it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Use basis transformations to  triangularize the basis, i.e. to the form $\,(x+cy, dy)$

$(a,b) = (x\!-\!2y,3x\!+\!y) = (x\!-\!2y,\overbrace{7y}^{b-3a})$

$(13x\!+\!16y,11x\!+\!13y) = (\underbrace{2x\!+\!3y}_{a-b},11x\!+\!13y) = (2x\!+\!3y,\underbrace{x\!-\!2y}_{b-5a}) = (\underbrace{7y}_{a-2b},x\!-\!2y)$

**Remark** $\ $ As in the extended Euclidean alorithm you can augment the reductions to keep track of the generators in terms of the original basis if so desired.